# Webview in Facebook / Messenger apps messing up my "Sign in with Facebook" button on my website

Tags: facebook, authentication, webview, messenger

I have a problem with the facebook and messenger app. when a user presses the URL of my website inside the app, it's opened inside the webview browser of the facebook or messenger app itself. so when the user wants to buy something on my website and presses "sign in with facebook", it doesn't work because facebook discontinued support for "sign in with facebook" for webview.

the button works fine on desktop or on mobile in a regular browser.

what is the appropriate solution for this?

the button works fine in safari, chrome, on iphone and android, but when opening my website thru a link posted on facebook or shared in messenger, the button is unpressable because Facebook discontinued the button "sign in with facebook" compatibility for webview.